# In angular 2 how do you do a html route using routerlink

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

**This is my current attempt for the html:**

```
 <a [routerLink]="['home']">HOME</a>
```

**This is my ts file route:**

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './index';

export const HomeRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];
```

**Error I get:**

Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("

**These are my package dependencies:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.2",
    **"@angular/router": "~3.1.2",**
    "angular2-google-map": "^0.1.8",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "0.6.25"
  }
```

**the component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'Home',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**the module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  exports: [HomeComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

**app.router:**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeRoutes } from './home/index';

export const routes: Routes = [
  ...HomeRoutes
];
```

**App module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes), HomeModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You're posting irrelevant code, and you're not posting the relevant code. Where is the code of the template causing that error? Where is the definition of your module, showing that you're using the router with the configured routes?

Comment: @JBNizet ive added the component and the module above.

Comment: I don't understand why you're creating a module just for your home component. You're still not showing the template causing the error. And you're still not showijg the application module, where routing must be configured. Read https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html.

Comment: @JBNizet ive added the template - all i have in home component is a link that im trying to get working but i get console errors with it. ive added the routing config above

Comment: What is a "HTML route"?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the route is this:  path: 'home' and this is my html link: <a [routerLink]="['home']">HOME</a>

Comment: I've asked you twice already to post you app module where the routes are configured. You refuse to do it. Read the tutorial where it's all explained. I'm done.

Comment: Well maybe are you missing just a *slash*? Shouldn't be `<a [routerLink]="['/home']">HOME</a>`?